# Probability with combination (assigning men and women to hotel rooms).

Tags: probability

I am totally clueless about this probability question. After spending an hour I decided to give up.

A hotel has $5$ single rooms, for which $6$ men and $3$ women apply. What is the probability that the rooms will be rented to $3$ men and $2$ women, assuming that each applicant has an equal chance of getting a room?

Comment: Aren't the only possible configurations $(3w, 2m), (2w,3m), (1w, 4m), (0w, 5m)$? Then the chance is $1/4$.

Comment: @brick well in the answers, that is not valid :)

Comment: ...and they are?

Comment: 10/21 seems the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total possible assignments are ${9 \choose 5}=126$. Rooms can be assigned to 3 men and 2 women in ${6 \choose 3} \cdot {3 \choose 2} = 60$ ways. So, the probability is $60/126 = 10/21$.